# How to draw the 3D cube using Javascript or SVG with given JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, react-hooks

I have JSON given below. Using this JSON need to create the 3D Box inside the 3D outline cube as shown in given image.I have this requirement but i am new in 3D kind of development. It will be great if someone can help on this. We can use skus array to create cube. Thanks in advance.[image]

```
{
  "request_id": "614bd0e3de7f3745708a9fa4",
  "completed_time_UTC": "2022-02-06T20:56:19Z",
  "tracks": [
    {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      "purchase_orders": ["1153511"],
      "vehicle_id": "be8c578a-c59c-4348-8148-50cfbeb5a6cd",
      "vehicle_type": "TRAILER_48T",
      "number_of_pallets": 14,
      "pallets": [
        {
          "purchase_orders": ["1153511"],
          "pallet_id": "fe76b310-d751-48eb-84f8-3ea47c7a94bd",
          "pallet_type": "BLANCA",
          "number_of_skus": 65,
          "skus": [
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [0, 54, 26]
            },
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [0, 0, 26]
            },
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 26,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [64, 59, 78]
            },
            {},
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [59, 54, 80]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "purchase_orders": ["1153511"],
          "pallet_id": "e693e8bd-e841-4a05-8912-aa0e837ba256",
          "pallet_type": "BLANCA",
          "number_of_skus": 65,
          "skus": [
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [0, 0, 0]
            },
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [0, 0, 26]
            },
            {},
            {
              "sku": "17503006575454",
              "length": 32,
              "width": 27,
              "height": 26,
              "position": [58, 54, 78]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "schemaName": "http://www.schema.org/logistics/1"
}
```